# How to queue users requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, httprequest

Users make requests from my app to third party API that have limitation 3 req/min. When user is one no problem to do it from controller for example. I want to queue all users request and send them with proper time intervals. I don't want to do it asynchronously way, but want to show to user a progress bar or spinner.  I've tried to do it with Sidekiq gem, but here is a problem with rendering result after job is done (my app controller tries to get the record from DB before creation). If is a standard way make this?

**controller**

```
  InitWorker.perform_async(current_user.id, params[:group][:domain], params[:group][:owner_id])

@group = Group.find_by_domain(params[:group][:domain]) || Group.find_by_owner_id(params[:group][:owner_id])
```

**worker**

```
here we creates a group
```

All of this takes data from form with `remote: true` and render new group by `js` Without worker it's work perfectly. But with code above it creates record in DB, but not renders anything, because can't find `@group` object.

**UPDATE**

I found gem `sidekiq-status` that maybe will help me, but for now can't understand, how to get data from worker. Maybe somebody have experience?

**controller**

```
job_id = InitWorker.perform_async(current_user.id, params[:group][:domain], params[:group][:owner_id])
      data = Sidekiq::Status::get_all job_id
      data # at this point I can see value stored in worker (with debuger) Hash here has 10 elements
      Sidekiq::Status::get     job_id, :g_sys_id # but here hash has only 5 elements, and value that I need is absent.  
      Sidekiq::Status::at      job_id #=> 5
      Sidekiq::Status::total   job_id #=> 100
      Sidekiq::Status::message job_id #=> "Almost done"
      Sidekiq::Status::pct_complete job_id #=> 5
```

Somebody please explain how to work with this!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it asynchronously. Otherwise you will block your application for other users. So you have to implement some sort of publish/subscribe mechanism, where users put their request to the external api into a queue and subscribe to the some async message channel, which pblishes notifications about the completions of the task.

In rails 5 there will be a standard way to it with ActionCable. It's already on master, so you can just try it with the newest rails version from github. For rails 4 you could use [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/)

Comment: Ok, let it be asynchronously. But by me approx time of worker job will not take a long time. Is it any way to render a record after its appear in DB?

Comment: only by publishing a notification message the user has subscribed to. After the appearance.